# Generate all possible combinations for 3 Columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheets with four columns.

[image]

I need to populate the Column D with all the possible combinations of the values in Columns A and C. Please take a look a the capture to see what I mean.

I found this following formula, but it use for 2 column.but i have 3 column.

i am using this code:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(rept(A1:A&char(9),counta(B1:B))),char(9)))&" "&transpose(split(rept(concatenate(B1:B&char(9)),counta(A1:A)),char(9))))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create all possible pair combinations without duplicates in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922267/how-to-create-all-possible-pair-combinations-without-duplicates-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can pass this formula back into itself to get the same result for three columns.*

#### Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(rept(A1:A&char(9),counta(ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(rept(B1:B&char(9),counta(C1:C))),char(9)))&" "&transpose(split(rept(concatenate(C1:C&char(9)),counta(B1:B)),char(9))))))),char(9)))&" "&transpose(split(rept(concatenate(ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(rept(B1:B&char(9),counta(C1:C))),char(9)))&" "&transpose(split(rept(concatenate(C1:C&char(9)),counta(B1:B)),char(9))))&char(9)),counta(A1:A)),char(9))))
```

This formula replaces the references to `B1:B` to a formula which transposes all combinations of column `B` and column `C`, and transposes all *those* combinations with those in column `A`.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(A2:A; A2:A<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(B2:B; B2:B<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(C2:C; C2:C<>""))))
```

[image]